# {awk: Command not found

Tags: bash, csv, if-statement, awk

I am new to bash coding so thanks in advance for your patience.

I will be processing 100,000's of image files over the coming weeks. As images arrive they have a raw name that needs to be modified. The name needs to be modified by looking up information for that image in a csv file and renamed accordingly. The prefix and suffix of the name together indicate exactly which record it is associated with and depending on which column the suffix matches, different name conventions are required. What am I doing wrong????

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

for file in *.NEF

do 

{awk '
BEGIN { 
FS=","
}

raw_name=$file
prefix="${file:0:3}"
suffix="${file:4:4}"

if ($28 ~ /$prefix/ && $24 ~ /$suffix/) 
{$100="New_prefix_1" "$raw_name";}

else 
{
if ($28 ~ /$prefix/ && $25 ~ /$suffix/) 
{ $100="New_prefix_2" "$raw_name";}
}
else 
{ 
if ($28 ~ /$prefix/ && $26 ~ /$suffix/) 
{$100="New_prefix_3" "$raw_name";}
}
else 
{
if ($28 ~ /$prefix/ && $27 ~ /$suffix/) 
{$100="New_prefix_4" "$raw_name";}
}
else 
{
if ($28 ~ /$prefix/ && $29 ~ /$suffix/) 
{$100= $4 "_" $2 "New_prefix_5" "$raw_name";}
}
else 
{
if ($28 ~ /$prefix/ && $30 ~ /$suffix/) 
{$100= $4 "_" $2 "New_prefix_6" "$raw_name";}
}
else 
{
if ($28 ~ /$prefix/ && $31 ~ /$suffix/) 
{$100= $4 "_" $2 "New_prefix_7" "$raw_name";}
}
else 
{
if ($28 ~ /$prefix/ && $32 ~ /$suffix/) 
{$100= $4 "_" $2 "New_prefix_8" "$raw_name":}
}
else 
{
if ($28 ~ /$prefix/ && $33 ~ /$suffix/) 
{$100= $4 "_" $2 "New_prefix_9" "$raw_name";}
}
else 
{
if ($28 ~ /$prefix/ &&  $34 ~ /$suffix/) 
{$100= $4 "_" $2 "New_prefix_10" "$raw_name";}
}
else 
{mv $file  ~/Rename_error/$file.NEF}
}
END }' Data.csv
```

Comment: The error says the problem quite clearly `{awk` is not a command the shell knows about. That being said there are other problems too. `$file` in the awk-script isn't doing what you think. The shell doesn't expand variables in single quoted strings. You'v'e got shell/awk confusion as to what you can do where. You've got lines like `prefix="${file:0:3}"` (which is shell) in the awk script itself, etc.

Comment: Remove the `END}` and remove the `{` before `awk`. Also, look up awk syntax, I suggest ´man awk`. Also your hashbang should not be awk I believe but bash or something.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple errors in your code (also see Etan Reisner's comment). A quick fix might be this. Oh and please indent and format your code, it makes it so much more readable.

```
#! /bin/bash

for file in *.NEF; do
    raw_name=$file
    prefix="${file:0:3}"
    suffix="${file:4:4}"

    awk -v raw_name="$raw_name" -v prefix="$prefix" -v suffix="$suffix" '
        BEGIN {
            FS=","
        }

        {
            if ($28 ~ /prefix/ && $24 ~ /suffix/) {
                $100="New_prefix_1" raw_name
            } elif ($28 ~ /prefix/ && $25 ~ /suffix/) {
                $100="New_prefix_2" raw_name
            } elif ($28 ~ /prefix/ && $26 ~ /suffix/) {
                $100="New_prefix_3" raw_name    
            } elif ($28 ~ /prefix/ && $27 ~ /suffix/) {
                $100="New_prefix_4" raw_name
            } elif ($28 ~ /prefix/ && $29 ~ /suffix/) {
                $100= $4 "_" $2 "New_prefix_5" raw_name
            } elif ($28 ~ /prefix/ && $30 ~ /suffix/) {  
                $100= $4 "_" $2 "New_prefix_6" raw_name
            } elif ($28 ~ /prefix/ && $31 ~ /suffix/) 
                $100= $4 "_" $2 "New_prefix_7" raw_name
            } elif ($28 ~ /prefix/ && $32 ~ /suffix/) {
                $100= $4 "_" $2 "New_prefix_8" raw_name
            } elif ($28 ~ /prefix/ && $33 ~ /suffix/) {
                 $100= $4 "_" $2 "New_prefix_9" raw_name
            } elif ($28 ~ /prefix/ &&  $34 ~ /suffix/) 
                $100= $4 "_" $2 "New_prefix_10" raw_name
            } else 
                system('mv 'file'  ~/Rename_error/'file'.NEF')
            }
        }
    }' Data.csv
done
```

Note that this embedded awk script seems to be poorly written. This is untested since there is no sample input and output.

Comment: Hello, thanks for taking the time to look at the code. Basically I have lots of incoming .NEF files that arrive with a name of xxx_yyyy.NEF where x = prefix and y = suffix. The prefix is the same for 9999 files, and when 9999 is reached the prefix will then change e.g. from 000 to 001. With the .NEF files comes a csv file which contains all of the relevant information such as whether it is a calibration image or whether it is an image that is a datapoint.

Comment: All of the necessary information to rename a file is contained in the row (which has 58 fields) that is uniquely identified by the prefix and suffix together. The only way that I have been able to figure out to identify the row is by using awk. Once the row is found, information from other fields in the csv file need to be added the .NEF filename e.g. family and genus ($4 and $2).

Comment: From what you are saying there is probably a better way to do this. I modified as per the instructions of ShellFish and added in some echo commands to see what the variables below for file in *.NEF are doing. $raw_name returns *.NEF, $prefix returns *.N and $suffix returns F. I also get a syntax error at raw_name=$file with the following (where line 12 corresponds to raw_name=$file:  context is
  } elif ($28 ~ /$prefix/ && $26 ~ /$suffix/) >>>  { <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 12
awk: syntax error at source line 26
 extra }
 missing )